# Error trying to download an XML file

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, download

I'm trying to download an XML file, the file already exists in the specified path, I am not familiar with VB and *probably this code is not right*, I need help just in it to be able to download an existing xml file, here's the **code**:

```
Protected Sub DownloadFile(ByVal sPath As String)
        Dim TargetFile As New System.IO.FileInfo(sPath)
        Response.Clear()
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +
            TargetFile.Name)
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", TargetFile.Length.ToString())
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
        Response.WriteFile(TargetFile.FullName)
        Response.End()
End Sub
```

The **error** returned in the console:

> Uncaught Error: *Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException*: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

Contextualizing the **problem**:

I have serialized an object and created an XML file, then I would simply like to download this file, my difficulty is to download the file.

```
Dim oObj1 As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(eSocial.Eventos.evtTabHorTur.eSocial))
Dim sFileName = Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".xml"
Dim sPath = Constantes.Ambiente.CaminhoSite & "temp\" & sFileName
Dim oFile As New System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath)
oObj1.Serialize(oFile, eSocialCamposXml)
oFile.Close()
```

Comment: Is this ASP.NET VB?

Comment: @Jaxi Yes, the `vb.net` tag says this

Comment: No, I mean is this `WinForms` or is this `ASP.NET`

Comment: @Jaxi ASP.NET, I'll specify this in the question, thanks.

Comment: How do you trigger download? Is that from some control inside UpdatePanel maybe?

Comment: @j.v. I have a button that serializes the object, creates the xml and then calls those functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you are having difficulty downloading but there is nothing in the code except showing writing a file and then serializing a file.  You would be using a 'StreamReader' or similar manner to READ a file.  Here is a simple example.  Say I have an xml structure on a file location with the schema like:

```
<root>
    <test>Data</test>
</root>
```

I could write this in VB.NET to get it:

```
Sub Main()
  Dim xmlFile As XDocument
  Dim fileLocation = "D:\\Test Code\\Test.xml"
  Using sr = New StreamReader(fileLocation)
    xmlFile = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd())
  End Using

  Console.WriteLine(xmlFile.Root.Element("test").Value.ToString)

  Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer helps me read an xml file, maybe it was not clear, I want to download this xml file, it would be something like: `Download (xmlFile)`, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Where is the file at?  Your 'Download' routine takes a location and then attempts to put it as part of a response.  When you say 'Download' I think you may want to rephrase your question to be: "How do I add a file to an HTTP Response".  Just guessing as you are not stating what System or defined type that Response is.  Regardless I would still use a streamreader to replace 'Dim TargetFile As New System.IO.FileInfo(sPath)' as that is getting a reference to a file, not getting the file.

Comment: My download attempt was based on answers to this question [Downloading File from Server to Client in asp.net](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?426162-Downloading-File-from-Server-to-Client-in-asp-net), I'm not familiar with VB, excuse any ambiguity in the question, I'll try with the stremreader.

Comment: The big question is that I have the XML file path, but I'm not sure how to get the client to download that file.

Comment: I guess what is the intent?  My intent is to download the file into memory as an object of 'XDocument'.  I can then do whatever I want with it.  You seem to be following some method on a forum to do what I am not seeing.  Adding this to a WebResponse I am not getting what that is getting you by the question.  Unless you provide more context.  Plus that page is ancient old, 2006 was pre .NET 3.0.  If you are doing anything that is new as of writing this there are probably more efficient ways of doing what you are trying to do.